# Processing xml file to remove elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I've just picked up some tasks manipulating XML files. I've started reading up on some basics but thought I'd ask the great and good here if some XSLT processing will do what I need it to once I'm up to speed.

I have an XML file that has roughly the following structure (in the main body of it):

```
<p><no>12345</no>
<line>Lots of text here that I want to get rid of but need to keep the text in any <ref>tags like this</ref></line></p>
```

At the end of the day the file is imported into Excel but as it stands it is huge and processing it to remove any `<line>` tags without `<ref>` is a long job, and even then the file is still pretty bloated. I'd like to reduce the excess text if at all possible. I think that I should be able to remove any `<line>` without a `<ref>` tag and similarly any `<p>` without a `<ref>` tag, but is it possible to strip the actual text out?

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes.  One generally writes a transform that simply does nothing with the nodes you want to omit, or else that explicitly transforms them to nothing.  But we are not a coding service.  If you cannot work out the details for yourself then show us what you come up with and ask specific questions about whatever is causing you trouble.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want to (a) keep `<line>` elements if they contain any nested `<ref>` elements; or (b) remove all `<line>` elements and nested text but keep any `<ref>` elements that were nested inside the `<line>` elements. Look up "XSL identity transform" to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Delete all p or line element with no descendant ref -->
    <xsl:template match="p[not(descendant::ref)]|line[not(descendant::ref)]"/>

    <!-- Identical Transformation -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I'll look over this and the links and see what I can sort. Good to know it can work though before I continue with my efforts.